# Counting the number of times each element of an array occurs in a file

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, java-io

I wrote the below code to answer the above question. Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong.

I would expect to see the code return the exact number of times each element in the array occurs in a text file. Regardless of spaces, tabs, line breaks etc.

```
public class counter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {
        String[] wordname;
        wordname = new String[] {"harry","ron","george","fred"};
        File file = new File("file.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        for(int i=0; i < wordname.length; i++){
            scanner.useDelimiter(wordname[i]);
            int occurences = 0;
            while(scanner.hasNext()){
                scanner.next();
                occurences++;

            }
            System.out.println(wordname[i] + ": " + occurences);
        }
        scanner.close();

    }
}
```

**Output:**

harry: 6

ron: 1

george: 0

fred: 0

**File:**

    harry harry ron george harry harry 
    harry harry har 
ron ron ron ron         fred
    fred fred george
    harry

Comment: What is your output? Can you give an example? Seems like it might only go through it once.

Comment: show the content in text file also.

Comment: Output: 
harry: 6
ron: 1
george: 0
fred: 0

File: 
harry harry ron george harry harry 
harry harry har ron ron ron ron   fred
fred fred george
harry

Comment: As your code is, you are trying to read the entire file for each word. In that case, you should initilaize and close the `Scanner` inside your `for` loop, not outside .

Comment: My bad I initilaize it and it works! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> You should split using White Space instead of word and your code scan file multiple time it also make performance down.
>
> So it is good to perform the same task in this way :

```
public class Counter {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String[] wordname;
    wordname = new String[]{"harry", "ron", "george", "fred"};
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String string : wordname) {
        map.put(string, 0);
    }
    File file = new File("file.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    scanner.useDelimiter("\\s+");
    String word;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        word = scanner.next();
        if (map.containsKey(word)) {
            map.put(word, map.get(word) + 1);
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        //read whole file to string only once
        String fileContent = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        String[] wordname = {"harry","ron","george","fred"};
        // filter each name and count occurrences
        for (String name : wordname){
            long count = Arrays.stream(fileContent.split(" ")).filter(s -> s.equals(name)).count();
            System.out.println(name + " : " + count);
        } 
    }
}
```